# Weird behaviour while POSTing a JSON through arduino's ENC28J60 module

Tags: c, json, post, arduino, arduino-c++

I've managed to set up a function to POST JSON data through my Arduino. I'm using webhook to test it and I'm experiencing some weird behaviour with it. The JSON data is not created where I would expect it to. Any help with explaining this would be appreciated.

```
#include <EtherCard.h>

// ethernet interface mac address, must be unique on the LAN
static byte mymac[] = { 0x74,0x69,0x69,0x2D,0x30,0x31 };

byte Ethernet::buffer[700];
static uint32_t timer;

const char website[] PROGMEM = "webhook.site"; //my router's address

// called when the client request is complete
static void my_callback (byte status, word off, word len) {
  Serial.println(">>>");
  Ethernet::buffer[off+300] = 0;
  Serial.print((const char*) Ethernet::buffer + off);
  Serial.println("...");
}

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Serial.println("\n[webClient]");

  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac) == 0)
      Serial.println("x{\"city\":\"Paris\",\"temp\":18.5}"); /// << JSON message is created here, and the first character of the message is removed
  if (!ether.dhcpSetup())
//    Serial.println("DHCP failed");

  ether.printIp("IP:  ", ether.myip);
  ether.printIp("GW:  ", ether.gwip); 
  ether.printIp("DNS: ", ether.dnsip); 

  if (!ether.dnsLookup(website))
//    Serial.println("DNS failed");

  ether.printIp("SRV: ", ether.hisip);
}

void loop () {
  ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  if (millis() > timer) {
    timer = millis() + 5000;
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("<<< REQ ");
    ether.httpPost(PSTR("/fe6f00eb-30ed-4b59-8908-fa3ec13c2485"), website, PSTR("Content-Type: application/json"),
       PSTR(""), my_callback); // PSTR("") because the message is created after .begin function is called
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the JSON data supposed to come from? I don't see any JSON data in the call to `ether.httpPost`. I see that you are printing some JSON data to the serial port, but why would that do anything?

Comment: That's exactly the question, PSTR in ether.httpPost is empty because it does nothing, while printing it in the serial port sends it to the server.

Comment: You said you were experiencing weird behaviour. What behaviour are you experiencing? Your comment makes it sounds like the code works fine but you are confused about how the code works. That's different from "the code has weird behaviour".

Comment: Yes, it works in some way I can't say I do understand, but you also have asked why would printing JSON data to the serial port do anything, and that's what I want to find out.

Comment: Printing JSON data to the serial port prints JSON data to the serial port. It doesn't send it over HTTP. I think that you think it sends JSON data over HTTP, but it actually doesn't.

Comment: I understand that it doesn't send it, but alas I recieve the data on the server using this exact code. With the parameter of httpPost being empty, and the only thing matching is the Serial.print's content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205955/discussion-between-snowshoot-and-user253751).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino has two completely separate address spaces: program memory, and RAM. Normally, pointers point to RAM.

`PSTR("hello")` puts the string "hello" into program memory and returns its address within program memory. If you read from this pointer, you actually read from data memory at the same location, and get some completely unrelated data. You need to use `pgm_read_byte` to read from program memory (which the ENC28J60 library doesn't do).

Your `PSTR("")` happens to have the same address as the second byte of the string you are printing in `setup`.

The solution is to remove `PSTR()` around the POST data.

I'm not sure if it is documented which parameters need to be in program memory, but I found the function [here](https://github.com/njh/EtherCard/blob/8206fa18b718b017b971311afe17fc648503920f/src/tcpip.cpp#L539) which reads them. It appears that `$F` means to read a string from program memory and `$S` means to read a string from RAM. `client_postval` is read using `$S`.